# Does Google App engine has a support for Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-app-engine, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby

Presently, all the links at [Google](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/) are saying that they are not supporting GAE for rails 3.1

Looking out for some constructive steps to work out GAE with rails 3.1 on eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

AppEngine does not directly support Rails. You might have some luck with running Rails through JRuby as Java is supported on AppEngine, but given how many easy hosting solutions there are that support Rails natively, you might find that you are trying to pound a square peg into a round hole.